# Editing a C array from within a function

Tags: c, arrays, function

I am trying to do this:

```
int a[5];
foo(){
    a[1]=7;
}
void main(){
    foo();
    //At this point, I want the value in a[1] to be equal to 7
}
```

Is there some way of making this work in C without passing `a` to the function `foo`, which is not possible in my application (interrupt handler on a microcontroller).

Comment: @chux Thanks, that was a typo. The problem still stands, though.

Comment: what is wrong with what you are doing? global variable is the name of the game.

Comment: Code all ready does what you want - what is the _unresolved_ issue?

Comment: But make it `volatile` if you are modifying it from an ISR

Comment: I just ran that example, it does what you want.  What is your question?

Comment: @kdopen is on the right track. OP: Suggest rather than talking about an ISR, add it to the post.  If `foo()` is the ISR, suggest `ISR_foo()` for clarity, and show how _other_ code accesses `a[]`.

Comment: Compiling it and running it should make it work.

Comment: @kdopen: `volatile might be insufficient for concurrent systems. Depending on the system, OP has to use atomics.

Comment: `foo()` is a strongly deprecasted signature and marked for removal from the standard. Use a correct prototype-style declarator. It is also plain wrong if you don't intend to return an `int` result.

Comment: "deprecasted" -> "deprecated" (who inserted the `s`?)

Comment: `void main()` is not standard

Answer (score 3):

If the global array `a` is modified in an interrupt control routine, you should define it as:

```
volatile int a[5];
```

`volatile` tells the compiler that the array elements can change asynchronously while the program is executing, for example because they can be modified by an interrupt service routine, or because the memory location is a hardware register whose value can change upon some external event.  Accesses to such variables must always generate code that reads or write the variable as specified in the code, unlike regular variables for which the compiler can often make valid assumptions about their value if have not been modified since last written to.

Furthermore, it is not recommended to use such short meaningless names for global variables.

Also note that your prototypes for `foo` and `main` are incorrect.  They should be defined as:

```
void foo(void) {
    a[1] = 7;
}
int main(void) {
    foo();
    // At this point, I want the value in a[1] to be equal to 7
    // ...more code
}
```

Comment: You tell him, chqrlie.  Top-notch programmers afoot.

Comment: `volatile` does not guarantee atomic access. Without further measures this still might produce invalid results. Worse: those possibly occur only once in a while, dependening on internal timing. Use `stdatomic` or ensure otherwise correct reads & writes.

Comment: @Olaf: I'm afraid the whole chapter about `stdatomic.h` is among the most obscure parts of the C Standard, far more abstruse than discussions on `restrict` or *effective type*... I doubt the skill level of the OP is compatible with anything more than `volatile` at this point. Hopefully the microcontroller can access an `int` atomically, otherwise making this an array of `char` should solve the problem. We are talking about an ISR on a microcontroller, not multiple treads running on multiple cores with out of order memory accesses.

Comment: @chqrlie: So just because OP cannot understand atomics, he should use a potentially wrong approach which can result in very subtle and pretty hard to debug - even for an experienced developer - faults? Well, the obvious alternative is to lock interrupts (or the one for the handler) around any access. We don't know how many cores the target has, but if there is only one, it should work (if the intrinsics imply memory barriers). Otherwise he ist lost.